# Google Sheets V4 spreadsheets.batchUpdate : Invalid requests appendDimension: No grid with id: 0

Tags: google-sheets-api

Why we got this error with an empty dummy spreadsheet with just one empty sheet trying to append a row to the first sheet ?

To recreate try the following:

1. Create an empty spreadsheet, it will contain one default sheet
2. Add another empty sheet called "Sheet 2" in the prev spreadsheet
3. delete the default spreadsheet, the first

> Now we want append a row to "Sheet 2"

Unfortunately the spreadsheet is private on gsuite and is not public accessible, but you can follow the previous steps to reproduce

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1feeE6Glv_TEE3lAi4Pd3BWblLo7jwPgSMyjATHY5SM8/edit?usp=sharing

This sheet was created before Sheets V4 release, if I create a new sheet copying all cells from old one it works but we have many old spreadsheets to port and it would be a time consuming job

## API test

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%221feeE6Glv_TEE3lAi4Pd3BWblLo7jwPgSMyjATHY5SM8%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22appendDimension%22%3A%7B%22length%22%3A1%2C%22sheetId%22%3A0%2C%22dimension%22%3A%22ROWS%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D

## Request

> THIS BODY WAS BUILT USING THE GOOGLE CODE EDITOR at `developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate` the same code was tested using the Java API with same perameters, we want to add a row to the first sheet

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "appendDimension": {
        "length": 1,
        "sheetId": 0,
        "dimension": "ROWS"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## Response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid requests[0].appendDimension: No grid with id: 0",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

If you follow the initial steps until step 2 the response will be `200 OK`, so we think we are not referring the first sheet using a zero-based sheetId with value 0

Comment: not valid question.

Comment: `appendDimension` is not a request, it is a field. What exactly are you trying to do with this request?

Comment: the request body as I pasted here is generated using the code editor at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate , so I cannot understand how could it be wrong, I simply used the editor to test the request, you can use your spreadsheet id to build a similar request, also try this create an empty spreadsheet, add a sheet, and delete the first sheet ...

Answer (score 1):

### The error comes from the `sheetId`

Mind that sheet Ids are not incremental. The first sheet will always have the Id `0`, but the second will NOT have the Id `1`. And if you erase the first sheet, its Id will NOT be passed to the second sheet.

To find out the Id of your sheet you can either

- use the method [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) specifying the `fields` `sheets` -this will return you information about the sheets including the `sheetId`
- or extract the Id from the spreadsheet Url.

If the Url is something like

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXXXXX/edit#gid=110036182
```

the `sheetId` is `110036182`